# SwiftUI: @main method should not be called on the main thread

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm running into this warning but I'm not sure whether it's valid or not, and if it is, how to fix it.

[image]

This is the warning that appears in my main class:

[image]

These are options in my schema:

[image]

### Thanks a lot!

Comment: This has been a problem for a while that seems related to WebKit. Usually this is just a noisy warning that you can safely ignore : https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/714467?answerId=734799022#734799022

Comment: We need more debugging details to answer this. Try to narrow it down. Just because the message is raised on the `@main` struct does not mean it is caused by code in it. This could be some view or action further down.

Comment: Keep commenting out till you isolate the issue probably you are doing something synchronous that blocks the main thread. Commenting out would be my approach

Comment: In my case, I could track this down to having an image view loading an image from the assets catalog. However, I don't see how this is supposed to be an issue. And [AyncImage](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/asyncimage) does not seem to be intended for loading bundle images.